# Is there any way to determine if a field is being tracked by using a SOAP API method call?

Tags: api, soap, history-tracking

I was wondering if there was any way to determine if a field is being tracked by using a SOAP API method call? It doesn't appear as if the describeSObjects actually returns me this information.

Thanks in advance.

Nathaniel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you can do is run query on *Object*History table and see if your field is there

like this:

```
SELECT count() FROM LeadHistory where field ='name'
```

One Problem is that if there is no data in History table then you will not get accurate result.

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000glm9AAA

Comment: Thanks. yes, as you point out, there is a problem if the field has never been changed. But if there is nothing else to determine it, then it will suffice for what I am needing it for. Thank you.